# prevent_duplicate_on still not working?

Tags: solspace-freeform

Does anyone know if Freeform's prevent_duplicate_on="ip_address" bug has been fixed?
It's still not working for me, though I'm using 4.0.12.

Has v.4.1.3 fixed this issue?

Thanks!

Peter T

Answer (score 1):

This is still a known issue, and has not yet been fixed.